# Semantic-ui Form Validation basic setup

Tags: semantic-ui

I'm new to semantic-ui and to javascript as well, so please bear with me. I have a basic form that I'm trying to get working with the built-in form validation semantic-ui provides. This form is part of a web app using node, express, and pug. The structure of the specific form (view) I'm working on looks like this:

[image]

Sorry for using a picture but I'm trying to keep this high-level.
As you can see, I have a form (with I believe the requisite classes), a submit button and a script block at the end, which is where I've got the validation code at the moment.

Here's my validation code such as it is:

```
     $('#new-password-form').form({
        on: 'blur',
        fields: {
          password: {
            identifier : 'password',
            rules: [
              {
                type  : 'empty',
                prompt: 'You must enter a password'
              },
              {
                type  : 'regExp[/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})/]',
                prompt: 'Your password must be at least 8 characters long, and contain upper and lower case characters, digit(s), and symbol(s)'
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }, {
          onSuccess : function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
          }
      });
```

The trouble is, validation isn't working. When I click the submit button the form attempts a regular get submit and it's as if the javascript isn't even there somehow. Yet it is there. Node is showing everything is properly fetched and loaded by the browser. Inspecting the rendered HTML shows everything is there, and I see no errors in the console. The page appears to have loaded all the requisite files successfully as follows:

```
GET /enroll/new 200 31.281 ms - 2652
GET /stylesheets/style.css 200 0.859 ms - 735
GET /jquery/jquery.js 200 1.491 ms - 280364
GET /ui/semantic.min.css 200 1.508 ms - 628536
GET /ui/semantic.min.js 200 2.070 ms - 275709
GET /images/amm.png 200 2.068 ms - 25415
GET /ui/semantic.min.css 200 0.418 ms - 628536
GET /favicon.ico 404 9.768 ms - 1499
```

So what gives? Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Happy to provide more detail if what I have here isn't enough.

**Update:**

I extracted the HTML to a flat file, and relinked the assets (png, js, css) so there is no server involved at all. The page loads in the browser just fine. I get the exact same behavior (nothing happens when submit is clicked except the page reloads with get parameters—default non-js behavior AFAIK). It's making me think something is wrong with jQuery or javascript itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the problem... a missing ',' at the end of the "type:" row (regExp[/^(?=.*[a-z])...).

[image]

Now validation is working for both the static file, and the server version. For what it's worth coming from other languages where this is not an issue, javascript's ubiquitous use of inline functions and data structures nested multiple levels deep is something I've had a very hard time getting used to. Makes it all too easy to miss some critical little piece.

I guess let this be another example of a basic setup of semantic-ui that works... so long as you don't leave off any commas. (I fixed the code above for those that might want to copy/paste)